# React : URL Change But Component is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an app using react-router. When I load from the server everything works correctly. But when I try to hit a route through the Link component, it just changes the URL and the component doesn't get loaded. Can someone please help me how to solve this problem

```
<Router>
  <NavRemover>
    <ListRemover>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/organizationContact'>Organization Contacts</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/products'>Products</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/sales'>Sales</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/purchaseOrders'>Purchase Orders</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/shipment'>Shipments</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/everything'>Everything</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/reports'>Reports</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/settings'>Settings</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/dashboard/logout'>Logout</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ListRemover>
  </NavRemover>
</Router>
</SideWrapper>
</SideBar>
</Grid.Column>
<Grid.Column width={10}>
  <h1 style={{ float: "left"}}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={ Dashboard}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/organizationContact' component={OraganizationContacts}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/products' component={Products}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/sales' component={Sales}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/purchaseOrders' component={PurchaseOrders}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/shipment' component={Shipments}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/everything' component={Everything}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/reports' component={Reports}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/settings' component={Settings}/>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard/logout' component={LogOut}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: no errors in the javascript console? also if you're going to put `exact` on every route then you don't need a <Switch> component since it's impossible to have two routes match

Comment: @azium when I refresh page with desire route it can be render but with ( Link ) it not rendering data